# Is there a refactoring tool for SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, refactoring

I would like to know if does anybody know a freeware refactoring tool, in which I could rename some table columns and get those names also renamed in my stored procedures.

Does it exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only tool I'm aware of is [Redgate's SQL Refactor](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_refactor/index.htm).  Mine have generally been small enough I do them by hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you own Visual Studio 2010 Premium or higher, you can use the Database Edition (Visual Studio Database Edition or DBPro) tools that come with that edition. It will do this for you, and much more.